# convex border-top and border-bottom with css?

Tags: css, border, line

I am trying to have a border only for top and border with a line that is thick (4px) in the middle and at the ends goes to zero. Like in the pic
[image]

```
.hervorheben{
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin-bottom: 1.6em;
    margin-top: 1.6em;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    border-top: 1px solid #105322;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #105322;
    padding: 19px;
    margin: auto auto;
}
```

Do you know how to do so with only css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can`t make border like that but you can manage with Pseudo-element (after) like following

```
.your_class {
    position: relative
}

.your_class:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 100%;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Enjoy....

Comment: Thanks that works :-)
How can I get a line above and below a div with a bit margin? I tried this, but didnt worked for me.


.hervorheben:before {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 4px;
    background: #105322;
    border-radius: 100%;
    content: "";
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    
}

.hervorheben {
     position: relative;
    }

 .hervorheben:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    height: 4px;
    background: #105322;
    border-radius: 100%;
    content: "";
    left: 10%;
    top: 0;
}

Comment: you change top or bottom property with positive or negative value